# How to change webpart custom property in sharepoint 2010 using javascript?

Tags: web-part, javascript, sharepoint-foundation

I want to change Custom Property of Webpart using javascript.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you be more specific? with property do you mean any public property of your web part class which appears on web part edit panel? that is what i understand from custom property and if so, it not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are some options but imo easiest one is to use Client Object Model:
see [SP.WebParts.WebPart.Title](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee557725.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I figured I'd post a solution I came up with.  I haven't tested in SharePoint 2010, but it's possible to update any web part property using JavaScript CSOM: http://almondlabs.com/blog/update-web-part-properties-csom/

Comment: Thanks for posting! One of our guidelines here is that we do not accept link only posts. If you could, please summarize your blog post so that if it is deleted or moved in the future others who come looking can still get an understanding of what you found.